# c++11 unrestricted unions example

Tags: c++11, unions

I read http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#unions

but I can't compile the given example:

```
union U1 {
    int m1;
    complex<double> m2; // ok
};

union U2 {
    int m1;
    string m3;  // ok
};

U1 u;       // ok
u.m2 = {1,2};   // ok: assign to the complex member
```

Results in:

```
main.cpp:85:8: error: use of deleted function 'U1::U1()'
     U1 u;       // ok
        ^   
main.cpp:75:11: note: 'U1::U1()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     union U1 {
           ^   
main.cpp:77:25: error: union member 'U1::m2' with non-trivial 'constexpr std::complex<double>::complex(double, double)'
         complex<double> m2; // ok
                         ^   
main.cpp:86:5: error: 'u' does not name a type
     u.m2 = {1,2};   // ok: assign to the complex member
     ^   
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Questions:

I thought that in a nonrestricted union the first element will be constructed if no default constructor is manually given. Is this true and how to write a working example?

The following one will also not compile:

```
class Y
{   
    public:
        constexpr Y() {}
};  

union X
{   
    int a;
    float b;
    Y x;
    //X(){}
};  

X x;

int main(){}
```

The same error messages:

```
main.cpp:112:7: error: use of deleted function 'X::X()'
     X x;
       ^   
main.cpp:104:11: note: 'X::X()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     union X
           ^   
main.cpp:108:11: error: union member 'X::x' with non-trivial 'constexpr Y::Y()'
         Y x;
           ^   
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: I only want to provide a short example. Having data members or not did not change the behavior. The problem is that I can not create an instance. And my expectation was that the first element of a union will be default initialized. Both could not be seen in the example :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the standard, [class.union] mentions in paragraph 2 (in the notes) tells this :

> A union can have member functions (including constructors and
>   destructors), but not virtual (10.3) functions. A union shall not have
>   base classes. A union shall not be used as a base class. If a union
>   contains a non-static data member of reference type the program is
>   ill-formed. At most one non-static data member of a union may have a
>   brace-or-equal-initializer. [ Note: If any non-static data member of a
>   union has a non-trivial default constructor (12.1), copy constructor
>   (12.8), move constructor (12.8), copy assignment operator (12.8), move
>   assignment operator (12.8), or destructor (12.4), the corresponding
>   member function of the union must be user-provided or it will be
>   implicitly deleted (8.4.3) for the union. — end note ]

Since your class has not-default constructor, the compilation fails.

Paragraph 3 even provides an example :

```
union U {
int i;
float f;
std::strings;
};
```

and says :

> Since std::string (21.3) declares non-trivial versions of all of the special member functions, U will have an implicitly deleted default constructor, copy/move constructor, copy/move assignment operator, and destructor. To use U, some or all of these member functions must be user-provided.

---

Bjarne wrote the same thing :

> If a union has a member with a user-defined constructor, copy, or destructor then that special function is deleted; that is, it cannot be used for an object of the union type. This is new.

but wrong examples. Both `std::string` and `std::complex` have non-default constructors. Therefore, unions with those require union's constructor.

Comment: Which means that simply the given example from Bjarne is wrong :-) OK!

Comment: @Klaus happens to the best ;) see edit for further explanation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the presence of `m2` in the union. Because complex has a "user-defined" constructor, the constructor for the union that contains it is `deleted`.

"If a union has a member with a user-defined constructor, a copy operation, a move operation, or a destructor, then that special function is deleted for that union;
that is, it cannot be used for an object of the union type.", The C++ Programming Language, p. 215.

```
union U { int m1;
complex<double> m2; // complex has a constructor
string m3; // string has a constructor (maintaining a serious invariant) 
};
```

"It is fortunate that U won’t compile." (same reference)